# From Special Function to global Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In the first run we do this:

```
$(document)
    .off('pagecreate','#MAT1000P00')
    .on('pagecreate','#MAT1000P00', function() {
        $(document)
           .off('click','#MAT1000P00-listview li')
           .on('click','#MAT1000P00-listview li', function() {....
```

for our first page. Now we want a function to do this on any page like this:

```
$(document)
    .off('pagecreate')
    .on('pagecreate',function (event,ui) {
        var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
        var activePageId = activePage[0].id;
        $(document)
            .off('click', '#' + activePageId + '-listview li')
            .on('click', '#' + activePageId + '-listview li', function() {...
```

but the new code doesn't work... why?

Comment: You should read what event delegation does in jQuery (how .on works) and what it does.

Comment: Can you explain a little about what you're trying to do here. Removing/attaching events doesn't seem like the most efficient pattern you could be using.

Comment: Thanks to Rory for the better format an your comment. we prettify our code a little bit like this....

Answer (score 1):

Now we found a solution to globalize our function. We change the document-Element as ID to the mobile-container and now it will be run:

```
$(document)
.on('pagecreate',function (event,ui) {
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').on('click','li',function() {....
```

Comment: Use the "edit" link under your question to add information... Answers should be answers